# Laravel 5.1.19 Artisan make:auth is not available

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed the latest version of laravel 5.1.19.

I've tried running:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

But it's returning:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]           
  Command "make:auth" is not defined.  
  Did you mean one of these?           
      make:test                        
      make:request                     
      make:migration                   
      make:seeder                      
      make:middleware                  
      make:controller                  
      make:provider                    
      make:policy                      
      make:event                       
      make:console                     
      make:job                         
      make:listener                    
      make:model                       
      make:command
```

Is this command no longer available?

I'm on a mac os x by the way.

Comment: In my case I create a project using 'laravel new myproject' command. It created a  Laravel 6 instance instead of 5.7 which I wanted. So check how you created your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that command is not available as the Auth feature comes default by the [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) package.

If you check the [Illuminate/Auth/Console](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/tree/master/Console), which is the place of console commands for the auth package, you will only see that the only available command is `auth:clear-resets`

You can see from the [commit](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/commit/4c7e6550a542e24acea7ef86a818997b68da0104) that `make:auth` has been removed for a year.

Comment: So there's no longer any quick way to add the Auth - Login / Register functionality?

Comment: No, but you can add your own command on your `app/Console` directory.

Answer (score 3):

**Check your Laravel Version if your vesion similar to 6.0.***
then, follow these steps -

1. use this command `composer require laravel/ui`
2. `php artisan ui vue --auth`
3. `npm install` then `npm run dev`

this is use for latest laravel version 6.0.*

Answer (score 1):

php artisan make:auth is not available in laravel 5.1
try to update your composer ( composer update ) and check in your file composer.json if 
laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

If any one needs make::auth in laravel 6.0,

php artisan make:auth is not available in laravel 6.0

try this

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
```